# Codeigniter require_once() error when implementing reCaptcha

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha

I'm getting the following error when implementing recaptcha.  I'm not sure how to clear up the path error.

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'F:\xampp\htdocs\cyoa\application\controllers/recaptchalib.php' (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in F:\xampp\htdocs\cyoa\application\controllers\cyoa.php on line 132

controller:

```
public function register_insert()
{
    require_once ('/recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "xxx";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
```

view:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "xxx";
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller line is the issue. If it's in the same directory as the controller file, simply: `require_once ('recaptchalib.php');`

Comment: The recaptchalib.php file is saved in the view folder.  I'm not sure how to route the path to that folder from the controller.

Comment: I tried using __DIR__ but it gave me the path of the controller.  Is there any way to use a relative path to the view to avoid hard coding it?

Comment: Did you try `../views/recaptchalib.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong slash. '\' to '/'. If the captcha.php is in the same directory you just use

```
 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
```